# How to void the authorize.net transection in magento

Tags: magento, void, authorize.net

I want to void the transection done by authorize.net in magento on some condition.
I have the transection id and all details.
Please let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

$transactionId=60032060090;
$referId=123456;

$paygate = Mage::getModel('paygate/authorizenet');

```
    $requestBody = sprintf(
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
            . '<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">'
            . '<merchantAuthentication><name>%s</name><transactionKey>%s</transactionKey></merchantAuthentication>'
            . '<refId>%s</refId>'
            .'<transactionRequest><transactionType>voidTransaction</transactionType><refTransId>%s</refTransId></transactionRequest>'
            . '</createTransactionRequest>',
            $paygate->getConfigData('login'),
            $paygate->getConfigData('trans_key'),
            $referId,
            $transactionId
            );

    $client = new Varien_Http_Client();
    $uri = $paygate->getConfigData('cgi_url_td');
    $uri = $uri ? $uri : $paygate::CGI_URL_TD;
    $client->setUri($uri);
    $client->setConfig(array('timeout'=>45));
    $client->setHeaders(array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
    $client->setRawData($requestBody);

    $debugData = array(
            'url' => $uri,
            'request' => $requestBody
    );

    try {
        $responseBody = $client->request()->getBody();
        $debugData['result'] = $responseBody;
        echo 'dddddd';
        echo $debugData['result'];
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $responseXmlDocument = new Varien_Simplexml_Element($responseBody);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $debugData['exception'] = $e->getMessage();
```

//          $paygate->_debug($debugData);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Transaction status fetching error.'));
        }